# Bloquear rotação android

Tags: java, android

Desenvolvi um app android porem preciso que ele so fique em pé não pode deitar... Qual seria a melhor maneira de bloquear a rotação ?
Obrigado

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Você deve ir no manifest do seu projeto e para cada activity você deve adicionar a seguinte linha

```
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Exemplo

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: onde coloco no manifest ?

Comment: No arquivo AndroidManifest.xml abra-o, nele existe uma tag activity para cada activity do seu projeto dentro da tag vc adiciona a linha que eu disse acima  e como está no exemplo tbm acima

Comment: coloquei no manifest e nas activitys , porem não funcionou

Comment: Agora deu, estava colocando em local errado XD

Answer (score 3):

Coloque isso em cada Activity

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```